# Unable to set cart currency in index.php

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Craft: 2.6.2976
Commerce: 1.2.1341

I want to force currency depending on language (en_us and no). The user should not be allowed to choose.

I've added two currencies 1) EUR - base, 2) NOK.

Putting `define('COMMERCE_PAYMENT_CURRENCY', 'EUR');` in the index.php for the english site, and `define('COMMERCE_PAYMENT_CURRENCY', 'NOK');`in the index.php file for the norwegian site does not work.

The currency is always EUR.

To be clear: Using `{{constant('COMMERCE_PAYMENT_CURRENCY')}}` does output the correct currency as set in index.php, however the cart is what always remains in EUR (base).

Is this a bug in Commerce?

Answer (score 1):

How do you render the cart?

Using `{{ item.price|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency,convert=true) }}` instead of `{{ item.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried setting `define('COMMERCE_PAYMENT_CURRENCY', 'EUR')` in the index.php file and it works fine.

You just need to use

`{{ cart.paymentCurrency }}`

Not

`{{ cart.currency }}`